# How to get a gif from the Clock result?

Tags: export, animation, gif-format

I get a `Clock` graphics like

```
Dynamic@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Clock[6]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

But how to export a `.gif` or `.webp` from this result?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to first calculate a table of images and exporting those. Here is your example:

```
d = Table[
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, y}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-1, 1}}], {y, Pi/10,
     2 Pi, Pi/10}];
Export["test.gif", d]
```

[image]

Comment: Well this is my current private workaround, but not export the result of Clock...

Comment: To export a GIF you need a table of images. I do not know a way around this.

Comment: But when I export `Manipulate` result to GIF  I don't need a series images

Comment: I have also used https://www.cockos.com/licecap/.

Comment: @Moo I have it on my computer, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with my windows11

Comment: Works for me and it is so easy. There are other variants out there - search for image to gif software and there are many other free ones and some online ones.